# Увеличение ID на один в таймере

Tags: c#, sql

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема. Я смог наконец-то сделать механизм перехода по сайтам, но теперь возникла проблема, как можно вызывать функцию, например, каждые 10 секунд. Пробовал в таймере, эффекта нету. Вот код, который я пытался всунуть в таймер:

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer++;

        MySqlConnection cnt = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        try
        {
            cnt.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd3 = cnt.CreateCommand();

            cmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = '" + timer + "'";
            MySqlDataReader readURL = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
            while (readURL.Read())
            {
                URL = readURL["URL"].ToString();
                webBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
                labelUrl.Text = "URL: " + URL;
            }
            readURL.Close();
        }
        finally     
        {
            cnt.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Мне нужно так чтобы при срабатывании таймера(интервалом 10 сек), срабатывал тот код что в его событии. А он не срабатывает((( и ID **НЕ** увеличивается

Comment: А таймер вообще запускается? Может он в стопнутом состоянии и не тикает...

Comment: Да он запускается после нажатия на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ID = '" + timer + "'";
```

Попробуйте так

```
WHERE ID = " + timer;
```

Comment: Не работает(

Answer (score 1):

убедитесь что изначально при запуске программы переменная timer проиниализирована ( пожалуй следует ей присвоить 1 )
и искать где сбрасывается этот timer. не бесконечно же ему расти=)

Answer (score 0):

Что-то я не вижу, где меняется в таймере переменная timer, по которой происходит выборка

Comment: Код обновил, но эффекта нету(

Comment: ну что тогда можно сказать, втыкните ShowMessage в таймер, узнайте реально ли он работает. Если работает, проверте кол-во записей, возвращаемых запросом

Comment: Выводит сообщение, но какие записи нужно менять я не знаю(

Comment: Вот подскажите, как нужно увеличивать переменную timer(int) на 1 каждый раз как срабатывает таймер? Вот я сделал label который показывает какой ID в данный момент просматривается, и я заметил, что он увеличивается на 1, но через секунду опять уменьшается на 1....

Comment: я, конечно, не специалист по c#, но можно ли в нём так вот запросто вставить число в строку "SELECT * FROM t_links WHERE ID = '" + timer + "'"; ? Может в этом дело?